# WPF, Modal Loader, Thread stop responding on touch events

Tags: c#, wpf, modal-dialog, touch, loader

I'm using a Modal Loader in a WPF Application to indicates to the user some background processing.

All works fine with keyboard and mouse, but when it runs in a Windows tablet the application freezes executing this procedure:

```
public void Complete(bool focusOnWhoCall = true)
{
    try
    {
        Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
    }
    catch { }
}
```

Running with the remote debugger, when froze, I pause the running. The visual studio execution pointer is on InvokeShutdown. Then I continue and it executes... It keeps freezed... I pause again and it stopped in the same point.

I uploaded this video on youtube to show the problem: https://youtu.be/IryEJ-YF168

I start using the mouse. All fine. When I use the touch at the first time its freezes... I don't know what to do anymore...

I make a project sample, every can download here: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=F4B7C28FAD05ECCD!3743&authkey=!AHs6dcCjRGJmB4c&ithint=file%2czip

Thank's in advance!